# How to select multiple rows with fake data in Snowflake

Tags: sql, unit-testing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, is there an easier way to select multiple rows of fake data in memory without loading actual data into a table? Below is a sample query showing how I currently generate an object containing multiple rows of fake data.

```sql
with
  fake_row_1 as (
    select
      1 as num,
      'one' as txt
  ),
  fake_row_2 as (
    select
      2 as num,
      'two' as txt
  ),
  fake_row_3 as (
    select
      3 as num,
      'three' as txt
  ),
  fake_table as (
    select * from fake_row_1 union
    select * from fake_row_2 union
    select * from fake_row_3
  )
select *
from fake_table
```

I am trying to test changes to query logic, and instead of loading and unloading test data into a test table, I am trying to stage a fake table in memory to more quickly validate expected results.

Ideally, I would be able to run a query similar to the following.

```sql
with
  fake_table as (
    select
      columns (num, txt)
      values (1, 'one'),
             (2, 'two'),
             (3, 'three')
  )
select *
from fake_table
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you do the union in the CTE?

```sql
with
  fake_rows as (
    select
      1 as num,
      'one' as txt
  union
    select
      2,
      'two'
  union
    select
      3,
      'three'
  )
select *
from  fake_rows
```

This might be a little cleaner:

```
with
  fake_rows as (
    select $1 AS txt,
           $2 as num
    FROM 
    (VALUES  
     (1,'one'),
     (2,'two'),
     (3,'three') 
         )) 
select * from  fake_rows
```

Comment: The example with `$1` and `$2` looks super clean. Thank you for the answer, Mike!

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need a CTE.  Using the [`values`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values) sub-clause in the [`from`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/from) clause

> allows the specification of a set of constants to be used to form a finite set of rows.

The syntax also allows you to specify an alias for the table name and column names like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES  
  (1,'one'),
  (2,'two'),
  (3,'three') 
) AS fake_rows (num, txt)
```

Which will yield the following table `fake_rows`

| NUM | TXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | two |
| 3 | three |

Comment: Thansk @JayRizzo - glad it helped!  Although I'm going to rollback to my original answer.   Your example was correct, but trying to limit the scope to just the problem statement without adding in new details (i.e. regex, filtering, etc.)

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks again! "Don't Have A Good Day, Have A Great Day!"

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your question here, you can generate hard coded data like above within a create table statement and that should get you what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement. I'm wondering whether there's something simpler than writing one `select` statement per row. For example, in Python we can define nested arrays, and ideally I would love to be able to use a single `select` statement to produce multiple rows at once. I'll try to clarify what I'm hoping to do in the question.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-function.html#examples @MartyC. this can help you with that